# Layer 7 Load Balancer vs API Gateway vs Load Balancer + Routing Service

Tags: aws-api-gateway, load-balancing, api-gateway, system-design

I'm new to system design. Sometimes, as an entrypoint to a system, I see a layer 7 load balancer being used. Other times, I see an API gateway. Yet other times, I see a dedicated routing service (which does endpoint-based routing) behind a layer 4 load balancer.

I've read a few articles on the internet, but I don't quite understand when you would want to use which. Is there ever a time where you would have an API gateway behind a load balancer? Is it common practice to point a DNS record to an API gateway instead of a load balancer?

Can someone please disambiguate this for me?